# Impala analysis exception from views

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a database which has a view created off other views which are created off other views (a data engineer built the views not me)

In Hive I can do this but its slow, so I want to use Impala

```
select * from table limit 5;
```

In Impala I get an error, have tried invalidate metadata and refresh with no luck.

```
"ERROR: AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: lower(BIGINT)."
```

what reason could this happen? Never seen this type of error before. Is there a way to do this recursively?

```
show create table;
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, be aware that Hive and Impala are distinct solutions, with distinct SQL parsers, supporting a distinct set of functions and features. A syntax that is valid in Hive may not be valid in Impala. Some table formats defined with Hive may not be supported by Impala *(e.g. ORC, or Parquet with a BINARY column)*.

In this specific case, the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) appears to match the [Impala documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions) for function `lower()` *(caveat: check what versions you are using)*.

But there's a big catch: `lower()` takes a String and produces a String. **It is not a number function. That smells like a gross mistake** such as confusing `lower()` -- convert some text to lowercase -- and `floor()` -- get the integer value that is equal or less to a decimal value.

Check with your so-called Data Engineer what he/she was trying to do, and make sure the views were properly tested *(or are properly tested after the correction is made)*. Hive clearly applies some implicit type conversions that enable queries to run, even though it makes no sense and produces goofy results.

Comment: yeah, I had to just follow the create table statement down multiple levels and describe tables then finally I found a statement that had lower(bigint type). Wonder if there was an easier way to debug?